# Multicolumn form in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, pdo

Although everything looks fine in my program (e.g. register2.php), I have some syntax and binding issues. As it keeps throwing the error on line 73 even though the data successfully entered my database named "webprojadmin", and the table named "users".

here is my connected PDO database:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$host = "127.0.0.1:3308";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "webprojadmin";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$optionen = array(
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
  );

try {
  // Create connection
  $cxn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $optionen);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $cxn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  //echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The"." ".$dbname." "."database is great." . PHP_EOL;
  //echo "Host URL: " . $host . PHP_EOL;
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

And here is my program, register2.php

```
    <?php
require "dbcxn.php"; 
?>

<center>
<div>
<h1>Add a new web user account</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Full Name:<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="enter your full name"></p>
        <p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter your email address"></p>
        <p>Password:<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="enter passowrd"></p>
        <p>Type<select name="utype">
                            <option value="FA">Academic, Faculty & Staff</option>
                            <option value="UG">Undergraduate Student</option>
                            <option value="PG">Postgraduate Student</option>
                            <option value="AU">Undergraduate Alumni</option>
                            <option value="AP">Postgraduate Alumni</option>
                        </select><p>
        <p>Bio:<br><textarea id="textboxid" type="text" name="bio" placeholder="May you introduce to us, briefly?"></textarea></p>
        <p>Awards:<br><textarea id="textboxid" type="text" name="awards" placeholder="Have you received any awards? If yes, what are they?"></textarea></p>
        <p>Publications:<br><textarea id="textboxid" type="text" name="pub" placeholder="Have you published any written works? If yes, what are they?"></textarea></p>
        <p>Thesis Topic:<br><textarea id="textboxid" type="text" name="ttopic" placeholder="What is the title of the Thesis you are doing/about to do/recently done?"></textarea></p>
        <p>Thesis abstract:<br><textarea id="textboxid" type="text" name="tabstract" placeholder="If you have told the thesis topic, what is it about? Tell us briefly. If not, leave it blank."></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="btn_register" value="Create an account"/></p>
    </form>
</div>
</center>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["btn_register"])) //button name "btn_register"
    {
    $fullname = strip_tags($_POST["fullname"]);
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $utype = $_POST["utype"];
    $bio = $_POST["bio"];
    $awards = $_POST["awards"];
    $pub = $_POST["pub"];
    $ttopic = $_POST["ttopic"];
    $tabstract = $_POST["tabstract"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, pass, utype, bio, awards, pub, ttopic, tabstract) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$pass', '$utype', '$bio', '$awards', '$pub', '$ttopic', '$tabstract')";
    echo ("<pre>\n".$sql."\n</pre>\n");



    if(empty($fullname)) {
        $errorMsg[]="Please enter username"; //check username textbox not empty 
       }
       else if(empty($email)) {
        $errorMsg[]="Please enter email"; //check email textbox not empty 
       }
       else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errorMsg[]="Please enter a valid email address"; //check proper email format 
       }
       else if(empty($pass)) {
        $errorMsg[]="Please enter password"; //check passowrd textbox not empty
       }
       else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
        $errorMsg[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters"; //check passowrd must be 6 characters
       }
       else
       { 
        try
        { 
         $select_stmt=$cxn->prepare("SELECT fullname, email FROM users 
                WHERE fullname=:ufname OR email=:uemail"); // sql select query

         $select_stmt->execute(array(':ufname'=>$fullname, ':uemail'=>$email)); //execute query 
         $row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

         if($row["fullname"]==$fullname){
          $errorMsg[]="Sorry username already exists"; //check condition username already exists 
         }
         else if($row["email"]==$email){
          $errorMsg[]="Sorry email already exists"; //check condition email already exists 
         }
         else if(!isset($errorMsg)) //check no "$errorMsg" show then continue
         {
          $new_pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //encrypt password using password_hash()

          $query = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, pass, utype, bio, awards, pub, ttopic, tabstract) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email', '$pass', '$utype', '$bio', '$awards', '$pub', '$ttopic', '$tabstract')";

          //$query2 = $sql;
          //$query2run = $cxn->prepare($query2);
          //$query2exec = $query2run->execute();
          //$row=$query2run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          $insert_stmt=$cxn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, pass, utype, bio, awards, pub, ttopic, tabstract) VALUES (:ufname,:uemail,:upass,:uutype,:ubio,:uawards,:upub,:uttopic,:utabstract)");   //sql insert query     
          if ($insert_stmt->execute(array( ':ufname' =>$fullname, 
                                          ':uemail'=>$email, 
                                          ':upass'=>$new_pass, 
                                          ':uutype'=>$utype, 
                                          ':upass'=>$bio, 
                                          ':upass'=>$awards, 
                                          ':upass'=>$pub, 
                                          ':upass'=>$ttopic, 
                                          ':upass'=>$tabstract))) {

           $registerMsg = "Register Successfully..... Please Click On Login Account Link"; //execute query success message
           header("refresh:1; index.php");

          }
         }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
         echo $e->getMessage();
        }
       }
      }

if(isset($errorMsg))
{
 foreach($errorMsg as $error)
 {
 ?>
  <div>
   <strong>WRONG ! <?php echo $error; ?></strong>
  </div>
    <?php
 }
}
if(isset($registerMsg))
{
?>
 <div>
  <strong><?php echo $registerMsg; ?></strong>
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
</section>
```

Comment: Maybe the error is in `$insert_stmt->execute`? You repeat ':upass' instead of changing it to a new bindParam

Comment: <?php if ($insert_stmt->execute(array( ':ufname' =>$fullname, ':uemail'=>$email, ':upass'=>$new_pass, ':uutype'=>$utype, ':ubio'=>$bio, ':uawards'=>$awards, ':upub'=>$pub, ':uttopic'=>$ttopic, ':utabstract'=>$tabstract))) { ?> 

Edited, but still throws the same error